# Card.io sdk not reading expiry date

Tags: ios, credit-card, scanning, card.io

I'm trying to scan my master-card (Titanium) using Card.io SDK. Scanner scan the card number properly but it is failing to read expiry date. I have to to enter the date manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dave from card.io here.

Yes, as you have observed, at this time the card.io SDK scans only the card number, and not the expiry date or other information.