# Card.io failing to read expiry date

Tags: credit-card, card.io

We are using code below, but this is not scanning the card expiry date. Any advice?

```
Intent scanIntent = new Intent(this, CardIOActivity.class);

// customize these values to suit your needs.
scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_EXPIRY, true); // default: false
scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_CVV, false); // default: false
scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_POSTAL_CODE, false); // default: false

// MY_SCAN_REQUEST_CODE is arbitrary and is only used within this activity.
startActivityForResult(scanIntent, MY_SCAN_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Card.io sdk not reading expiry date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24030414/card-io-sdk-not-reading-expiry-date)

Answer (score 0):

Scanning expiry is an experimental feature, and as such, may not work all the time.